# Indented line of code doesn't show as block of code in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting

Regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670258/2128327) when I view it in Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m (64-bit) on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit. The answer has only 1 line of indented line of code (with more than 4 spaces), when viewing the answer it shows like normal text. When it's only 4 spaces it shows up correctly.

[image]

At first I thought it was not formatted, and when I tried to edit it, turned out that it's indented already, and the preview view it correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... It had 6 leading spaces. When I removed 2 of them (which it did not need) it is fine. Still odd.

Comment: @Matt AFAIK `>= 4` is indented. beside that, there is the inconsistency between the preview and the view

Comment: I am not saying there is not an issue. I saw the same thing in 48.0.2564.116. But a single line does not need more than 4 spaces as a code indent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer was from 2009, and there was likely something wrong with the Markdown parser when that answer was originally posted. The rendered output gets permanently stored for each post, and only updated when the post gets edited. So whatever bug was there has been showing through all this time.

Any edit whatsoever to that post would have forced it to be run again and saved a new version over the old one, to properly format it as code.

Comment: Cool. Good to know.